# RecyclerView with a Button inside

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to create a layout like this:

**Layout with pictures and button**

[image]

I have not idea how to do that. I've created RecyclerViews with different items, but something in common (like picture, videos, they all can be seen as a Media type). In this case the first item is a button (or an image acting as button) and the other ones are just pictures, so I can't have all them on a single list in the adapter, because they don't represent the same logic. An idea is to put in the position 0 another object that indicates it should be created as the button, and after that position the image list, but then I need to handle that the items aren't on the position i but in the position i+1, so I don't like that solution. There's any "clean" way to do this?

Comment: do you need the code?

Comment: Why not you use a GridView, it will suits more as seen form your layout.

Comment: You can use GridLayoutManager in RecyclerView instead of LinearLayoutManager and Multiple View Types

Comment: the problems isn't to show multiple view types, the problem is that in the position 0 will be an Image, not a Button, so if I show a Button instead an Image, the fisrt image will never be shown, and only will see from 1 to N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the  getItemViewType() and onCreateViewHolder() functions in the RecyclerView adapter like this:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int VIEW_TYPE_1 = 1, VIEW_TYPE_2 = 2;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position == 0){
        return VIEW_TYPE_1;
    }else{
        return VIEW_TYPE_2;
    }

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType){
        case VIEW_TYPE_1:
            // inflate the view with button
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_2:
            // inflate the view with image
            break;
    }
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
        case VIEW_TYPE_1:
            //set the viewholder for view type 1
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_2:
            //set the viewholder for view type 2
            break;
    }

}
```

You have to create a ViewHolder for each type of views.

Hope this can help you

Comment: That's what I meant. What will happen with Image in the position 0 on the Adapter?? it will never be shown because on that position will be shown the button, not the image.

Comment: You have to create 2 view holder in the adapter, one using a xml with the button view and other with the image view. In the position 0 the adapter will inflate the view with the button, and after the 0 will inflate the view with the image. Then in onCreateViewHolder you handle the view that was selected

Comment: what I always do in onBindViewHolder is Object object = list.get(position) if I do that I will have the problem I said, on position 0 of list I don't have a button, I have a picture

Comment: The conditional with position == 0 was just and example. You can use the same logic in getItemViewType. If the object is an instance that use a button, return the view type 1, and if is an instance that use an image, return view type 2. The important thing in the function is that you have to return the type of view in that position of the adapter

Comment: that's the problem! My adapter only haves picture's object, I don't have any button objet inside my adapter.

Comment: You can add a dummy object as the first in your list and, you inflate the button in that position. And the proceeds with the rest of the list using pictures